# How do I print the names in CodeHS 8.4.4: How Many Names?

Tags: python

This is what I'm supposed to do:

The first part of this exercise is the same as the first part of How Many Names? in the Control Flow module.

Some people have just a first name and a last name. Some people also have a middle name. Some people have five middle names.

Write a program that asks the user how many names they have. (If they have a first name, two middle names, and a last name, for example, they would type 4.) Then, using a `for` loop, ask the user for each of their names. Store the names in a list.

Then, use slices to separately print the person’s first name, middle name(s), and last name.

An example run of your program might look like this:

```
Number of names: 4
Name: Nora
Name: Stanton
Name: Blatch
Name: Barney
First name: Nora
Middle name(s): ['Stanton', 'Blatch']
Last name: Barney
Your program should work regardless of how many middle names the person has!
```

Hints

The index -1 may come in handy in a couple places.
You’ll need to use the `str` function to print the middle names.

I have found the correct answer to this problem. Here it is:

```
name_amount = int(input("How many names do you have? "))
namelist = []
index = 0
for i in range (name_amount):
    name = input("Name: ")
    namelist.append(name)
    index += 1
print "First name: " + namelist[0]
print "Middle names: " + str(namelist[1:-1])
print "Last name: " + namelist[-1]
```

Comment: Rather than a `try:except:` block (which in this code will not trigger the `except` by the way) why not a simple `if name_amount > 2:`?

Comment: Try removing your `try except` to see what error message is thrown out in the line: `print "Middle names: " + namelist[1:-1]`.  Knowing what the error is will certainly help you solve your problem

Comment: I just updated my code and added the error that it gives.

Answer (score 1):

You issue is in this line here:

```
print "Middle names: " + namelist[1:-1]
```

When you have more than 1 middle name `namelist[1:-1]` will be a list at least 2 long.  The `+` you use in this line is trying to concatenate the string `"Middle Names: "` with the list `["middlename1","middlename2"]`  and Python doesn't know what to do here so it thrown the exception:

`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

To fix this and get the format you want for the middle names (`Middle name(s): ['Stanton', 'Blatch']`) you need to tell python to turn the list into a string with `str()`  so your line should be:

```
print "Middle names: " + str(namelist[1:-1])
```

This will force python to turn your list into a string that can be concatenated and printed.

Answer (score 0):

Also add parenthesis around the line you want to print, for example:

```
print("Middle names: " + str(namelist[1:-1]))
```